# Youtube iframe embed that expands into featherlight lightbox (and works in FB timeline)

Tags: jquery, facebook, iframe, lightbox, featherlight.js

I just tossed the FB part in there in case there are any other issues I haven't encountered yet that I should be aware of.

I can get the iframe to open in the lightbox by following the first set of directions on the featherlight page and swapping in the iframe for the div in the example like so:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="small-3 display-light">
        <a href="#" data-featherlight="#mylightbox">Open element in lightbox</a>
        <iframe 
        id="mylightbox"
        width="398" height="224" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/T5Ap6rkyBHY?&w=398&h=224"></iframe>

    </div>
</div>
```

Problem is the same as with the example.  I don't want the iframe to be shown (or even loaded) until after the lightbox event is triggered.  So, what I really want is something along the lines of storing the iframe code as an html page, and having the lightbox fetch it.

This is what I assume the ajax example does:

```
<a href="#" data-featherlight="myhtml.html .selector">Open ajax content in lightbox</a>
```

but I'm new to jquery, and not quite sure what to do with the .selector bit.  Just puting in my url for myhtml.html doesn't work, so I'm assuming I need to connect it somehow.  Do I need to use the binding options they talk about, or is there something simpler I'm missing?

Answer (score 2):

There shouldn't be a need to put your things in a separate page, it's actually best if it is already preloaded in the page.

Just hide the `iframe` with a specific CSS selector, e.g.:

```
.row iframe { display: none }
```

Comment: OK, thx.  It looks like I'm headed in a bit of a different direction, but that makes sense for  the above as I don't want user to then be waiting for another load once they click on it.